# What spacing should I use for Unistrut supporting electrical conduit?

Tags: electrical, wiring, conduit, construction

When suspending electrical conduit from the ceiling in a warehouse (EMT or Rigid), that runs perpendicular across Unistrut, how far apart are the Unistrut allowed to be?

What type of conduit is allowed?  EMT or Rigid?

Answer (score 1):

Support is required as specified for the conduit - unistrut does not make any difference in the required support spacing.

For EMT, the required support is **within 3 feet of each termination**, and **a minimum of every 10 feet.**

I'm not as familiar with the support requirements for rigid, it's too rich for my blood. Whatever they are, they are not influenced by the support being unistrut.

Comment: GRC has the same strapping requirements. Most electricians will strap every 8' just to CYA. Some AHJ like to see at least one strap for every piece of conduit and one more strap at each 90 or 45 within 3'.

Comment: As you get into larger sizes rigid varies by size but I agree this RME 8' is normal.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the size and type of your conduit.

[image]